# Bounds on degree from bounds on derivatives

Tags: polynomials, approximation-theory

Let $f(x)\in \Bbb R[x]$ and $r(x)\in\Bbb R(x)$. Supposing we have information about the values taken by $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in certain intervals and also can bound their derivatives in these intervals, can we infer any upper/lower bound on the degree of the polynomial or the rational function?

For instance, if for every $x\in\{0,\dots,n\}$, $a \leq f(x) \leq b$ holds and $\exists x\in [0,n]\cap\Bbb R:|f'(x)|\geq c$, then $deg(f)\geq\sqrt{\frac{cn}{c+b-a}}=\Omega(\sqrt{n})$ is known.

I am looking for above kind of results.

http://www.jstor.org/stable/2949624 provides lower bound for polynomials.

Comment: Please state more precisely what you are asking for. What does it mean "we know"? If you know some analytic function exactly on some interval, you know it everywhere.

Comment: That is not what I meant. I mean if you know some values of the function and its derivatives, can be give any bounds on its degree?

Comment: Instead of explaining what you mean in the comments, state your question PRECISELY.